# does 0xlabs work with all tokens?

Tags: 0x

Can I use API to make a dapp that lets users buy low mcap tokens?

ATM I only get results for tokens like DAI, USDT, ETH. I would've thought if it aggregates uniswap, it'll aggregate any token that's got liquidity?

I've looked through the documentation and couldn't find anything regarding list of tokens.